# Where are the user's notifications stored?

Tags: support, notifications, database-design

Looking at the Stackoverflow's [DB architecture](http://data.stackexchange.com), I wonder where does each user's notification get stored?

For instance, someone answers a post I created, I am notified about it thanks to the top-bar with a red "+1".
Is there a specific `activity` or `notification` table that is read through WebSockets/SSE to create this notification?

Comment: SEDE doesn't hold the complete production schema. One of the things to remember is that voting is anonymous. The Votes tables holds the up- and downvotes but the userid field is empty.

Comment: @rene Ok for the votes, but what about the other kind of notifications as my post evokes? (post answer(containing the excerpt of the first words of the answer))

Comment: I don't know that. If that is information that can be shared I'm sure a dev will answer...

Comment: @rene Ok, no problem :)

Comment: Do notice that the api does provide that: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-notifications

Comment: Nice :), but I'm really interested in the architecture regarding DB tables. (of course, if it's not "secret")

Comment: @rene : how illegal votes are cancelled if SE don't keep a log of the votes from an user? Here is an example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/237701

Comment: @n.1 They do. The *highly secret* production tables contain that data. The publicly-visible data dump doesn't.